# How to fetch objects in PHP from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I'm trying to generate an Array of Objects fetched in the DB.

My code to attempt do that is this:

```
public function findAllObjects() {
    $conn = $this->openConnection();
    $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM content');
    while ($content = $result->fetch_object($class = 'Content')) {
        var_dump($content);
        $contents[] = $content;
    }
    $conn = $this->closeConection();
    return $contents;
}
```

If I print the value of "Content" inside the foreach loop using 
`var_dump` , the result it is the following:

```
object(Content)[4]
protected 'id_content' => string '1' (length=1)
public 'title' => null
public 'description' => null
public 'category' => null
public 'date' => string '2015-01-01' (length=10)
public 'townReceiver' => null
public 'author' => null
```

Obviously, the table Content have the entire information, but this code only fetch the `id` and `date`. Any suggestion to solve that? Thank you!

**EDIT**
`$class = 'Content'` it is the parameter  `class_name`, from official documentation:

> The name of the class to instantiate, set the properties of and
>   return. If not specified, a stdClass object is returned.

You cand find more at:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php
And this is the atributes of the `class` **Content**:

```
class Content extends Model {

protected $id_content;
public $title;
public $description;
public $category;
public $date;
public $townReceiver;
public $author;

function __construct($title = null, $description = null, $category = null, $townReceiver = null, $author = null) {
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->description = $description;
    $this->category = $category;
    $this->townReceiver = $townReceiver;
    $this->author = $author;
}

//Methods of the class...
```

**EDIT 2**
The problem is the `__construct` method. If I delete this method, `fetch_object` works fine. **What is the reason? Can't I use __construct with `fetch_object`?**

**EDIT 3**
The sollution that I find, with Ryan Vincent comment, is that:

```
function __construct($title = null, $description = null, $category = null, $townReceiver = null, $author = null) {
    if (!isset($this->id_content)) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->townReceiver = $townReceiver;
        $this->author = $author;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$class = 'Content'` supposed to  mean?

Comment: When declaring a function `($class = 'Content', ...)` assigns a default value. When *calling* a function it assigns to a meaningless variable.

Comment: I also strongly encourage you to use an existing, battle tested ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/). Writing your own proprietary one is counter-productive. This is a hard problem to solve correctly, and it's been solved very well many times over.

Comment: I assume you are using `mysqli`.And please, **always** use prepared queries with placeholders.  As already mentioned - the issue is that the object properties are set _and then the constructor is called_ ;-/ So, your constructor will need to check that the properties haven't already been initialized. I would just assigned null to the `id` when it is declared. If it is set then don't change the properties in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you @RyanVincent, I understood the sentence "sets the properties of the object BEFORE calling the object constructor" because your comment, so thank you. I will edit the principal post with a sollution that works for me. Can you check if is a good sollution? **Please, answer the question, and I will vote that it's the sollution.** Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem it's that the object was set BEFORE call `__construct` method, so, __construct override the object to null, as was defined.

To avoid this, I check if the id of the object is set; 2 possibilities:

1) If I want to generate a new content and store it into the DB, the id will be `null` because the id is assigned with the auto-increment option in the DB.

2) If I want to get the objects, the id will be set, and data won't be overrided.

So the sollution is this piece of code:

```
function __construct($title = null, $description = null, $category = null, $townReceiver = null, $author = null) {
    if (!isset($this->id_content)) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->townReceiver = $townReceiver;
        $this->author = $author;
    }
}
```